# show data row in specified number position

Tags: php

I have coding like this, showing data list, I want to show ads at row 3 and 6, please help me to resolve this query.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($random_id_ad) - 1; $i++)                              
   test   
   if row(position is 3 and 6)
       ads
   }                         
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$i** represents the current row in your code, so just change the if statement to this

```
if($i == 3 || $i == 6) {
    echo 'INSERT ADD CONTENT HERE';
}
```

[Loops](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp)